# Atmospheric re-entry speed

Tags: low-earth-orbit, reentry, geostationary

What would be the difference in atmospheric re-entry speeds from LEO and GEO, assuming a Hohmman transfer orbit from GEO to re-entry?  If I am getting the transfer orbit concept correct?

Comment: I wonder if there has been any reentry from GEO via a Hohmann transfer. The transfer would need too much fuel. Transfer to a graveyard orbit is much cheaper.

Comment: @Uwe If there was a station in GEO, is a Hohmann transfer the fastest way for an astronaut to get back to Earth, or would another way be more appropriate?

Comment: Astronauts have been in LEO, on a transfer orbit to Moon and back, in orbit around Moon and on the surface of the Moon. But no astronaut ever stayed in GEO.

Comment: @Uwe I am aware of that. I said "if there was a station..."  I am asking a hypothetical question.

Comment: @Bob516 There is little advantage to having a station in GEO. Uwe's point is that people went back from higher than GEO.

Comment: @Antzi. I am writing a piece of fiction where I have a station in GEO.  I know men have reentered from higher than GEO.  I am asking about the difference between LEO and GEO, not whether it has happened or is most practical.

Comment: For good piece of fiction you should find an important task to do by the astronauts, something that may be done only by astronauts and not by unmanned satellites and that may be done only in GEO but not in LEO.

Comment: @Uwe I have been wondering why you gave me advice on fiction writing when I asked a clearly hypothetical question about space exploration.

Comment: @Bob516 Just remember your comment written Dec 12 at 15:04 to Antzi.

Comment: @Uwe I remember it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy.

It would be similar to a [GTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_transfer_orbit) orbit.

The speed at perigee would be around **9.88 km/s**, actually a little bit faster due to the perigee being slightly lower than for GTO.